# How could I convert a string to Ptr{Cchar}

Tags: julia

I need as an argument to a C function i'm calling with `ccall`, a `Ref{Cchar}` (aka a char*)
How I could I convert my string to a Ref{Cchar} ?
Thanks a lot !
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling a function that takes `char*` you would typically use `Cstring`. From the [documentation on calling C](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/):

> The `Cstring` type is essentially a synonym for `Ptr{UInt8}`, except the conversion to `Cstring`
> throws an error if the Julia string contains any embedded NUL characters (which would cause the
> string to be silently truncated if the C routine treats NUL as the terminator).

so to call the `size_t strlen ( const char * str )` C function you can write:

```
julia> ccall("strlen", Csize_t, (Cstring,), "abc")
0x0000000000000003
```

or:

```
julia> ccall("strlen", Csize_t, (Ptr{UInt8},), "abc")
0x0000000000000003
```

If you are mutating the string you could do something like this:

```
julia> strvec = Vector{UInt8}(undef, 10)
10-element Vector{UInt8}:
[...]

julia> ccall("strcpy", Csize_t, (Ptr{UInt8},Cstring), strvec, "abcd")
0x00007f4ad6788a70

julia> strvec[1:4]
4-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x61
 0x62
 0x63
 0x64

julia> String(strvec[1:4])
"abcd"
```

or even with a Julia string:

```
julia> str = "test"
"test"

julia> ccall("strcpy", Csize_t, (Ptr{UInt8},Cstring), str, "abcd")
0x00007f4ad6fed6f8

julia> str
"abcd"
```

to get a pointer from a `String` or `Vector{UInt8}` you can call `pointer` but you can also, as shown above, just let `ccall` handle the conversion.